# What are some options for command line http performance testing?

Tags: performance, http

I am looking for a basic http performance tool.  Preferably command line, about the complexity of curl.  I want to run very basic scenarios, something like execute "http get http://server/resource" for 60 secs and collect the results.  Very basic.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ab - Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)

Comment: Excellent!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Meets my needs perfectly.

Comment: @jayray - It's a good tool, but really only does basic benchmark testing.  Look into JMeter if/when you get into more advanced or complex testing scenarios.  Oh, and there's curl-loader too.